# Post json to xamarin webclient api

Tags: c#, android, json, asp.net-web-api, xamarin

I want to post a jsonobject to my webapi. Using normal C# code i would use PostAsJsonAsync on my httpClient object. But that doesn't seem to be supported with xamarin. So my question is how do i post json to my api using xamarin webclient or webrequest?

Here is my code right now that returns null...

```
   protected async override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        var clientRequest = new ResourceByNameRequest
            {
                Name = "G60",
                UserId = "1"
            };
        HttpContent myContent = new StringContent(clientRequest.ToString());
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("XXX");
                var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
                var response = client.PostAsync("/api/Resource/ResourceByName", myContent, cancellationToken).Result;
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                //return result;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
//...

protected override void OnResume()
{

var request = HttpWebRequest.Create("Your_URL_XXX");
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";


var clientRequest = new ResourceByNameRequest
{
    Name = "G60",
    UserId = "1"
};

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    writer.Write(clientRequest.ToString());
}

try
{
    using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{

string error = "";
if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
error = string.Format("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0} | Description: {1}", response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription);
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))

{
    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
    {
        strResponse = "Response contained empty body...";
    }
    else
    {
        var cont = JObject.Parse(content);
        YOUR_OBJECT_RESPONSE.PROP1 = cont["Prop1"].NullSafeToString();
        YOUR_OBJECT_RESPONSE.PROP2 = cont["Prop2"].NullSafeToString();
        //...

    }
}
}
} 
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
    var pageContent = new   StreamReader(wex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();   
    }
}
```